# Best way to add only one instance of a number?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I have to create a C++ program that takes in two linked lists and creates a new linked list of nodes from both, but with only one instance of every number. So the output of 
list A = 1 --> 3 --> 1 --> 4 and list B = 4 --> 5 --> 12 would be 
list C = 1 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 12. The order of numbers in the new linked list does not matter. What I am having trouble with is how to keep track of each number so that I only add one instance of that number to my new linked list. The only thing I can think is to iterate through the nodes and check if the number is already there. But is there a better way?

Comment: Ideally, you would just stick everything into something like `std::set`, although I assume your teacher wants you to only use linked lists?

Comment: `std::unordered_set<int> s;...if (!s.count(node_data)) { add_node_data_to_list; } s.insert(node_data);}` -- There is your 3 line solution.  Now is this acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

[Sort](http://%20http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.c) each of the two input lists into ascending-order first, then you can just look at the first item at the head of each list, pop the smaller of the two off the head of its list, then append it to the tail of your new list — unless it is equal to the number currently at the tail of your new list, in which case just discard it.  Repeat until both input lists are empty.